# How do I start a gitlab-ce container via docker-compose with admin credentials already set up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with a Gitlab CE container:

```
services:
  // other services..
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
      - "127.0.0.1:8081:80"
    volumes:
      - '/etc/gitlab'
      - '/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - backend
```

On startup, this requires you to open the browser, go to(in this case) `localhost:8081` and manually input a password.

I'd like for this process to be automated(for local development and testing purposes).

Gitlab's own answers:

```
    gitlab-rails console production
    user = User.where(id: 1).first
    user.password = 'somethingsomething'
    user.password_confirmation = 'somethingsomething'
    user.save!
    exit
```

Which works if I ssh into the Gitlab CE container after everything is set up(takes minutes).

Running this directly via `command` does not work - presumably because the `gitlab-rails console` isn't ready to go yet the minute the container is up.

I've tried to manually create a `Dockerfile` with the `gitlab/gitlab-ce` image, used `COPY` to get the above script into the container and `CMD` it. However, as predicted, this fails as `gitlab-rails console` isn't ready yet on start-up. It takes a while.

Ideal scenario is that the container starts, installs Gitlab and does all the setup stuff; *then* sets the root admin password automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to set the `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` as an environment variable.

This works:

```
services:
  // other services..
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    restart: always
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = 'adminadmin'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
      - "127.0.0.1:8081:80"
    volumes:
      - '/etc/gitlab'
      - '/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - backend
```

When starting up the service, this is confirmed:

```
gitlab_1       |               == Seed from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/fixtures/production/002_admin.rb
gitlab_1       |               Administrator account created:
gitlab_1       |               
gitlab_1       |               login:    root
gitlab_1       |               password: adminadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed this issue on my side:

```
sudo docker exec -it container_name bash
// replace username by your user, for me it is root
gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[username]"
```

Answer (score -2):

I try the cbll response but doesnt work for me.

To change the root password manually in Docker Container Gitlab CE.

1. docker exec -it <git_lab_container> bash
2. gitlab-rails console

-----Wait until the console open----

3. irb(main):001:0> user = User.find_by_username 'root'
4. irb(main):001:0> user.password = "newpassword"
5. irb(main):001:0> user.confirmation_password = "newpassword"
6. irb(main):001:0> user.save!

Comment: `undefined method confirmation_password' for #<User id:1 @root>`